# How to create AlertDialog when transact or start a new Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public void loadDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogbox_delete_user_confirmation, null);

    subView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeleteUser);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Fill your Secondary Details");
    builder.setView(subView);
    builder.create();

    builder.show();
}
```

Here, I called the `loadDialog()` function in `onCreate()` method of the `Activity`.But the `AlertDialog` was not prompting when I load above particular `Activity`.
Simply i created `login` activity. After successful `login` new activity will start. But at the same time, I want to show the `Alert Dialog` box at while transaction of activities. How can I do that?

Comment: are you sure that loadDialog() is called ? place a log there and see if it prints or try to show a toast to see if you calling the function from correct thread as its UI and needs to be called from UI thread...

Comment: Oops! Even i call it inside the onCreate function,loadDialog() is not executing...what is the reason for that?

Comment: you will have to back track to see till which function the execution happens... including onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so, by basically two simple ways. Which are:-

- **Using `BaseActivity`:** In this case you need to create a `base activity` that will have your `AlertDialog` with it's `context`, (current your `dialog` is missing the context while transaction) whenever you want to show it you can show it by implementing the method after extending the `BaseActivity` from any other `child activities`. Steps are showing below :

  ```
   public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         public void showDialog(String msg)
         {
           // show the dialog
         }
       }

   public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity
      {
       public void someFunction()
       {
           showDialog("activity 1");
       }
   }

   public class Activity2 extends BaseActivity
   {
       public void someFunction()
       {
           showDialog("activity 2");
       }
   }
  ```
- **Using `Fragments`:** In this you can control it from your respective `activity` or `fragment` itself. But this is totally different approach from your current procedure.